# Where to save informations from Chrome Extension and retrieve it?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, storage

I have finished with developing main mechanism of my Chrome Extension but I need to do final step and enable saving informations that extension gets. I already saw that chrome.fileSystem API allows this but it can't be used with extensions and using chrome.storage isn't posibble in this case because of lot of data. Is it posibble to somehow save all of that informations to .json file in extension and retrieve it when user wants?

Comment: have you tried local storage in chrome or html.

Comment: With localstorage I can add new items only for defined one, but I can't add every new information in different item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for unlimited storage, you first need to add the `"unlimitedStorage"`-Permission to your [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage) file.

Then you can choose one of the following storage options:

- [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)
- [IndexedDB](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)
- [File System](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) (chrome only)
- [App Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)
- WebSQL (deprecated)

**More Info**

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage
- https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage
- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage
- https://github.com/summera/chromestore.js